# Regex to select only specific characters between two strings

Tags: regex

I have the following HTML:

```
<i>This is my first sentence.        

This is my second sentence.</i>
```

Using Regex (in SublimeText FYI) how can I select only the whitespace (including line breaks) between the two `<i></i>` brackets?

I have got this far where I can select all the characters, but how do I limit it to whitespace and new lines only?:

```
(?<=<i.).*?(?=</i>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/1986

Comment: A regexp can only match a contiguous substring, it can't match unconnected substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it with single regex, you can use a combination of regex

1. `<\s*i[^>]+>([\s\S]+?)<\s*\/\s*i\s*>`

[`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/vmUwXG/2)

This will give you values between tags `<i>` and text between tags is available in `captured group 1`, now you can loop through the matched values and find any `space` character

2. `\s+`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe this expression,

```
(?=\s*[\n\r])(\s*)(?=\S)
```

replaced with a single space () might be close to what you might have in mind.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2BLe8v/1) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through the captured group 2:
`(<i[^>]+?>)?([ \n]*)(<\/i>)?`

https://regex101.com/r/wcPwkU/1